# How can I overrule a LESS variable within a mixin?

Tags: css, less

I'm using LESS in one of my projects right now and I need to create some colour-schemes for different users. I'm building a portal and based on what kind of user logs in, the colour-scheme needs to change.

So in my mixins.less (which I can't modify) file I have:

```
@color-button-bg: #333;
@color-button-txt: #fff;
@color-button-fs: 1.5rem;
@color-button-fw: 500;
@color-button-hover-pct: 10%;

.base-btn-default(@type: button) {
    background: ~"@{color-button-bg}";
    border: 1px solid ~"@{color-button-bg}";
    color: ~"@{color-button-txt}";
    font-size: ~"@{color-button-fs}";
    font-weight: ~"@{color-button-fw}";
    &:hover, &:focus {
        @color-btn-hover: ~"color-button-bg";
        @color-btn-hover-pct: ~"color-button-hover-pct";
        background: darken(@@color-btn-hover,@@color-btn-hover-pct);
        border-color: darken(@@color-btn-hover,@@color-btn-hover-pct);
        color: ~"@{color-button-txt}";
    }
}
```

And in a separate file with client-specific mixins I tried the following:

```
/* Override default color with theme-color */
.theme-styling() {
  @color-button-bg: @main-theme-color;
}
```

Then finally I wanted to add a class to my `<body>` tag and style the colour-scheme based on that classname:

```
body.theme-a {
  #main-theme-color: teal;
  .theme-styling();
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I think it has something to do with scoping / Lazy evaluation, but I'm not that experienced in LESS yet, to see where my error is.

I created a Codepen for it, without the separate files and in a bit of a simplified form:
https://codepen.io/jewwy0211/pen/JVNZPv

Answer (score 0):

I've just played around with your codepen a bit. When you define the variable in your mixin, it does work, the problem is that you then don't use that variable in the mixin or in the class that contains the mixin.

So, if you've got 2 buttons like this:

```
<div class="wrapper one">
  <button>Theme 1</button>
</div>

<div class="wrapper two">
  <button>Theme 2</button>
</div>
```

You can call their theme-specific variable mixins in their respective classes to get the vars set, but you then must use the vars within the same class:

```
.wrapper.one {
  .theme-styling-1();
  background-color: @color-button-bg;
}
.wrapper.two {
  .theme-styling-2();
  background-color: @color-button-bg;
}

/* Theme Vars */
.theme-styling-1() {
  @color-button-bg: teal;
}
.theme-styling-2() {
  @color-button-bg: red;
}
```

EDIT: Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/mmshr/pen/OGZEPy

Comment: I don't quite understand, to be honest. Do you have a Codepen-example of your solution, so I can have a look at that?

Comment: @Jewwy I added a codepen link which illustrates my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: OK, I see what you did. But this way I need to redeclare all styling using that specific variable. So the mixin I created to use that LESS-variable in different ways (border-color, background and also the :hover/:focus styling) needs to be redeclared after each usage of the mixin. That makes the mixin not very useful anymore, except for all the styling apart from that different color. I was hoping for a solution where the LESS-variable could be put into the mixin, no matter what color is used.